# AngularJS $q - Return resolved directly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I use a method that expects a promise. Sometimes however, the `promise` is resolved instantly. Currently, if the `promise` is resolved right away, I still pass the promise, and use the following:

```
function instantAction()
{
    var defer = $q.defer();

    // Actions that are performed instantly

    defer.resolve();

    return defer.promise;
}
```

If there a way, to just return the resolve directly, such as something along the lines of `return $q.resolve()` and skip those two extra lines?

Comment: `return $q.when();` should work, but is far less intuitive and comprehensible.

Comment: Instantly means you have in memory data the you need to return with promise instead of going back to the server?

Comment: What do you mean by return the resolve directly? Here in this case it is resolved right away, Or did you mean you don't want to make the `instantAction` method implementation non-async in some cases?

Comment: `return $q.when(<someData>);` (but unlike Blackhole I find it far more intuitive and comprehensible).

Comment: @ExpertSystem Actually, it's strange to use a method whose name is `when()` for such a thing. But it's not really difficult to override the `$q` service to add a `resolve()` method, directly linked to `when()`, I agree!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Blackhole and @ExpertSystem said above,

`$q.when(<Data or 3rd-party Promise>)` will return a promise.

It's intended to make an Angular promise out of data or a 3rd party promise.

See the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: This is a great solution for returning a dummy promise in one line.  I used it for conditionally bypassing an unexposed `$http` service.